# RFC_READ_TABLE returns NULL

Tags: java, eclipse, sapjco3

I am using `RFC_READ_TABLE` function to retrieve list of tables:

```java
destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("ABAP_AS_WITH_POOL");
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
function.execute(destination); // This line of code is throwing error
JCoStructure returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");
```

But it's returning me null value, could you help me?

Giving this Exception:

> com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException: (126) TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE: TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE Message 300 of class DA type E

Complete code:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "It's not working" is not an accurate problem description.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Giving this Exception: com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException: (126) TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE: TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE Message 300 of class DA type E..........@vwegert

Comment: Small wonder, since you are calling the function module without specifying a table...

Comment: destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("ABAP_AS_WITH_POOL");
        JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");   
        function.execute(destination); // This line of code is throwing error            
                                                                                             
                                                                                             
JCoStructure returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");       .............@vwegert Thanks...